# Как экранировать спецсимволы на golang?

Tags: golang

У меня есть строка

```
{"function":"TrainingQuestionInfo","values":{"Question":"текст со спецсимволами / \ и т.д."}}
```

Мне нужно экранировать кавычки и слеши.
Как это сделать? Есть ли для этого какая-то функция?

Comment: Строку обычно надо экранировать перед передачей куда-то, куда вы будете её передавать?

Comment: разобрался - подходит такой вариант https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Quote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Quote

fmt.Println(strconv.Quote(`{"function":"TrainingQuestionInfo","values":{"Question":"текст со спецсимволами / \ и т.д."}}`))

Answer (score 1):

`\\` для слэша, `\"` для кавычки. Все как в сях...
PS. Автоматизация решения - сначала замена всех слэшей, потом - кавычек.

Comment: не-я хотел какую-то функцию.что б она это сделала

Comment: Так и напишите в вопросе, что вам нужна функция для экранирования. Правда, я не совсем понимаю зачем это...

Comment: Строку обычно надо экранировать перед передачей куда-то, куда вы будете её передавать?

Comment: @rekby зависит от того, куда ее надо передавать и в каком она виде уже есть...

Comment: В контекста программирования на go строка вроде как может быть только в одном виде: внутри переменной типа string, всё остальное это уже не строка, а что-то еще.

Answer (score 1):

Экранирование обычно зависит от того, куда эта строка передается.

Например можно использовать JSON:

```
b, err := json.Marshal("aaa\nbbbыыы")
fmt.Printf("str=`%v`, err=%v\n", string(b), err)
// выводит str=`"aaa\nbbbыыы"`, err=<nil>
```

[>>> код на playground <<<](https://play.golang.org/p/TBtcAu6rgb)

Answer (score 0):

От Строковые литералы (http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals):

- raw string literal поддерживает многострочный (но экранированные символы не интерпретируются)
- интерпретируемый строковый литерал интерпретирует экранированные символы, например '\n'.

Но если ваша многострочная строка должна включать backquote (`), тогда вам придется использовать интерпретируемый строковый литерал:

```
    `line one
      line two ` +
    "`" + `line three
    line four`
```

Вы не можете напрямую поставить backquote ( `) в строковый литерал строки (` xx ). 
Вы должны использовать (как объяснено в как поставить обратную кавычку в строку с возвратом в исходное положение"):

- "`" + ...